# Selenium c# SendKeys not send letter symbols

Tags: c#, selenium, sendkeys

I am testing a web application and need to hide the sidebar, but this action is performed by pressing the "S" key, however, chrome does not respond to sendkeys with this key, but responds to other non-letter combinations (if I send backspace or /, then everything works). Is there a way to emulate pressing the S key via selenium in a different way
My attempt:

```
new Actions(driver).SendKeys("S").Perform();
new Actions(driver).SendKeys(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")),"S").Perform();
new Actions(driver).Click().SendKeys("S").Perform();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys("S");
```

Also i try to send ascii and unicode code, but have no result.
Browser - Chrome.

Comment: Is the sidebar some sort of widget on the web page, or a native Chrome sidebar? Does it need an additional key like Control pressed down as well? Is the key case-sensitive?

Comment: The xpath you are using is on the body. My guess is that you need to find the correct element first?

Comment: This is a page widget, an additional key is not required, only the "S" button, the panel does not require case, but is sensitive to the layout (in a different input language, manual action also does not occur).

Comment: Using XPath on the panel itself also did not give results, but if i do this

`new Actions(driver).SendKeys("/").Perform();`
Element Search Input on sidebar handled this and set focus to itself.

Comment: Also, tests run on selenoid in docker container with linux, default language - en, in manual session sidebar handled keypress.